# Get xmlnode from most recent datetime stamp in XML

Tags: c#, xml

im trying to get XMLNODE "Price" from a XML File, the XML is huge by it's self and has many, many "Row" Elements in it. I'm trying to get the "Price" node, by going by latest "transactionDateTime" since it has a time stamp but im having trouble getting it to work.

```
XmlDocument xdocoA = new XmlDocument();
xdocoA.Load(Transation);
XmlNodeList ndlistA = xdocoA.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/rowset/row[@transactionDateTime]");
foreach (XmlNode xmlnodeA in ndlistA)
{
    LastTN.Text = xmlnodeA.Attributes["price"].InnerText;                               
}
```

XML File :

```
<eveapi version="2"> 
  <currentTime>2016-02-01 22:48:26</currentTime>  
  <result> 
    <rowset name="transactions" key="transactionID" columns="transactionDateTime,transactionID,quantity,typeName,typeID,price,clientID,clientName,stationID,stationName,transactionType,transactionFor,journalTransactionID,clientTypeID"> 
      <row transactionDateTime="2016-01-31 23:10:57" transactionID="4212499228" quantity="12" typeName="Spodumain Mining Crystal II" typeID="18624" price="900000.00" clientID="94420021" clientName="Gayle Rowen" stationID="61000400" stationName="4F6-VZ XI - Limited Sense" transactionType="buy" transactionFor="personal" journalTransactionID="12205145551" clientTypeID="1373"/>  
      <row transactionDateTime="2016-01-30 17:52:03" transactionID="4210791656" quantity="1" typeName="Small Polycarbon Engine Housing I" typeID="31177" price="500000.00" clientID="95987816" clientName="Lash Wolfram" stationID="61000575" stationName="6-8QLA V - Perrigen Falls Trade Hub" transactionType="buy" transactionFor="personal" journalTransactionID="12198662373" clientTypeID="1376"/>
      <row transactionDateTime="2016-01-30 17:50:44" transactionID="4210790391" quantity="1" typeName="BZ-5 Neutralizing Spatial Destabilizer ECM" typeID="19946" price="549999.99" clientID="920370728" clientName="Missniggins" stationID="61000884" stationName="OP7-BP V - Ivy Towers" transactionType="buy" transactionFor="personal" journalTransactionID="12198656389" clientTypeID="1377"/> 
    </rowset> 
  </result>  
  <cachedUntil>2016-02-01 23:15:21</cachedUntil> 
</eveapi>
```

> Please remember this XML is big and this is just a cut down version.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Parsing the timestamp? Or finding the most recent one?

Comment: Note that `rowset` element doesn't have closing tag

Comment: If you are comfortable with LINQ, try Linq to xml api.

Comment: i would paste the whole thing but it's stupidly big; sorry if it's missing a closing tag, im having trouble with getting the node it's self, i don't know how to do it. i'll post some more of the XML to give you a better idea, so in an example when now it'll give me the bottom "price" (549999.99) instead of 900000.00, this XML get's updated so it's gonne keep changing,

Comment: I would also seriously ask myself whether there is any other way of determining the current price than by obtaining a huge XML file of (perhaps) all transactions of that item and then querying it for the latest record.

Comment: @simen-s there isnt, it's a weblink, this is the only way it comes, in one big file

Comment: @VivekDev i've got no problems with giving LINQ ago, can you provide me with a sample?

Comment: `xmlnodeA.Attributes["transactionDateTime"]` should give you the transaction timestamp. You'll then need to parse that and compare it against the most recent timestamp found so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("dat.xml");

var mostRecentPrice = xml.Descendants("row")
                         .OrderByDescending(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Attribute("transactionDateTime").Value))
                         .First().Attribute("price").Value;
```

You can also order the rows by their transaction IDs given they are ascending:

```
var mostRecentPrice = xml.Descendants("row")
                         .OrderByDescending(r => r.Attribute("transactionID").Value)
                         .First().Attribute("price").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As based on comments, you want to obtain a specific node in a `XML` for a given **transactiondate**.

Following code might help.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);     

var output = doc.Descendants("row") 
    .Where(e=>e.Attribute("transactionDateTime").Value == "2016-01-31 23:10:57")
    .Select (e=> new { 
        price = e.Attribute("price").Value, 
        quantity = e.Attribute("quantity").Value    
    });
```

If you are looking for most recent transaction, you can do this.

```
var latestnode = doc.Descendants("row") 
.OrderByDescending(e=> DateTime.ParseExact(e.Attribute("transactionDateTime").Value,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ))
.Select (e=> new { 
    price = e.Attribute("price").Value, 
    quantity = e.Attribute("quantity").Value,
    Date = e.Attribute("transactionDateTime").Value
}).First();
```

Check fiddler [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0p5Vws) and [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sa2wHu)

Comment: but when this XML updates and the time stamp changes date / time will this fall oveR?

Comment: @BicPen Do you want to pick the latest first in any case?

Comment: i want to pick the most recent one

Comment: You cannot mention the "2016-01-31 23:10:57", since an update to the xml would change the latest one.

Comment: @BicPen  Is this fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I understand that you have the `Date`s as `string` s in the `ndlistA`.

To get the latest transaction, you can use this lambda:

```
var latestRowNode = ndlistA.Select(node => new { TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(node.Attributes["transactionDateTime"]), RowNode = node, Price = node.Attributes["price"] })
                           .OrderBy(row => row.TimeStamp )
                           .Last();
```

Here the latestRowNode would have:

```
latestRowNode.Row //Your row node
latestRowNode.TimeStamp // it's time stamp
latestRowNode.Price // it's price as string
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ-to-XML, you can cast `XAttribute` to suitable .NET data type directly, for example :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Transation);
var latestRow = doc.Descendants("row")
                   .OrderByDescending(r => (DateTime)r.Attribute("transactionDateTime"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
var latestPrice = (decimal)latestRow.Attribute("price");
Console.WriteLine(latestPrice);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zUJuQF)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
900000.00
```

**For reference :** [XAttribute Explicit Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute_operators%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)